# Filtering DataFrame on multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For my class I need to find the sepal length in the iris dataset that is between 4.5 and 6.
exact specifications are "Select the rows that that has sepal length greater than 4.5 but less than 6"
the given code (which the answer should be in this form) is

```
    subset=data[data['petal width (cm)']>2]
```

what I have is:

```
    subset=data[data[(['sepal length (cm)']>4.5 and ['sepal length (cm)']<6)]]
```

the main problem I am having is getting the syntax correct. in its current state, I get an error stating

```
    TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

If it is changed to

```
    subset=data[data[(data['petal width (cm)']>4.5 and data['petal width (cm)']<6)]]
```

I get the error

```
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

thank you

Comment: `subset=data[(data[(['sepal length (cm)']>4.5) & (['sepal length (cm)']<6)])]`. You need to wrap each condition in parentheses and create "and" logic with `&`. I suggest you read the documentation on [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: I understand why the parentheses, I will look into as to why a & is required but when I try your solution I get `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'`

Comment: My fault, there was a typo in there --  you need this `subset = data[(data['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5) & (data['sepal length (cm)'] < 6)]`

Comment: That worked. thank you. I realize that I did not wrap each one in parentheses and tried to add it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subset = data[(data['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5) & (data['sepal length (cm)'] < 6)]
```

Courtesy of @cmaher